# Did anyone use mongo3 as the gui interface on Mac?I can't run it

Tags: ruby, mongodb

When I run mongo3 after running `gem install mongo3`. I got the problems below

```
F, [2013-05-08T20:35:18.376873 #8487] FATAL -- : undefined method `helpers' for CollectionHelper:Module (NoMethodError)
/Users/shuxuan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo3-0.1.5/lib/helpers/collection_helper.rb:15:in `<module:CollectionHelper>'
/Users/shuxuan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo3-0.1.5/lib/helpers/collection_helper.rb:14:in `<top (required)>'
/Users/shuxuan/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/mongo3-0.1.5/lib/mongo3.rb:49:in `load'
```

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for now (from github discussion) is to use older sinatra.

```
gem uninstall sinatra 
gem install sinatra -v 1.3.3
```